# How to store y_pred variable result from “for-lop” values in numpy array or list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, arraylist, numpy-ndarray

I am writing code for `SVR`. I have datasets that have more than 2000 rows and 22 columns. After prediction at every iteration for y_pred by using `for loop` so I need to `store` all of the `y_pred` values which come from `for loop`. I want to store these values in a `list` or a `numpy array`. I am writing my code but it does not work. Please help me to write this code in a proper way. I know the role that is

```
numpyarray = np.empty((1001,2000, 23))
for i in range(1001):
    numpyarray[i, :] = numpyarrayfunction
```

Comment: But it does not work.

My full Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Make fake dataset
dataset = pd.DataFrame(data= np.random.rand(2000,22))
dataset['age'] = np.random.randint(2, size=2000)

# Separate the target from the other features
target = dataset['age']
data = dataset.drop('age', axis = 1)

X_train, y_train = data.loc[:1000], target.loc[:1000]

X_test,  y_test  = data.loc[1001], target.loc[1001] 

X_test = np.array(X_test).reshape(1, -1)
print(X_test.shape)

SupportVectorRefModel = SVR()
SupportVectorRefModel.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = SupportVectorRefModel.predict(X_test)
y_pred

for i in range(1, 1001):
    X_train, y_train = dataset.iloc[i:1000+i], target.iloc[i:1000+i]
    X_test, y_test = dataset.iloc[i], target.iloc[i]

    X_test = np.array(X_test).reshape(1, -1)
    print(X_test.shape)

    SupportVectorRefModel = SVR()
    SupportVectorRefModel.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = SupportVectorRefModel.predict(X_test)
```

My current code:

```
numpyarray = np.empty((1001,2000, 23))
    for i in range(1001):
        numpyarray[i, :] = numpyarrayfunction
```

Comment: **it does not work** - insufficient information!

Comment: You need to provide minimum working code, for example, we have no idea what "numpyarrayfunction" is, or how large your dataset is, or what modules you are using, etc.

Comment: The second half of the code you have above has the wrong indents and undefined y_pred. This code is not properly formatted.

Comment: @Bobby Ocean sorry for that. I have again updated my code. Now it's looking good. Please may check

Comment: what is numpyarrayfunction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
from sklearn import svm
import pandas as pd
import numpy  as np

dataset        = pd.DataFrame(data= np.random.rand(2000,22))
dataset['age'] = np.random.randint(2, size=2000)
target         = dataset['age'] 
data           = dataset.drop('age', axis = 1)

y_pred = np.empty((1000,))
for i in range(1, 1001):
    X_train, y_train = dataset.iloc[i:1000+i], target.iloc[i:1000+i]
    X_test,  y_test  = dataset.iloc[i],        target.iloc[i]
    X_test           = np.array(X_test).reshape(1, -1)
    model            = svm.SVR(gamma='scale') # Avoid the printed future warning. 
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred[i-1]      = model.predict(X_test)
print(y_pred)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I run my code then my looping is running and I want to store value from for loop.

Comment: I don't know what that means. It does take like 20 seconds to finish the for-loop. Did you wait for it to finish?

Comment: Yes, I try it. But it is looking also complicated. Mentor, is it possible to write this code by using Numpy array in an easy way

Comment: I edited so that it updates an empty array now. Is that what you want? I don't know what you mean by "complicated". This is YOUR code, all I did was add a list that gets append'ed to. The rest is yours.

Comment: Thanks for Your kind response. I used Your code but the loop is still running. After running 3 cycles it shows an error `IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1`.

 It is possible to write code as the `Numpy array`??

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're training on a range of data, technically you don't need the loops.

But, if you want to keep things your way, just try this:

```
y_pred_sol = []
for i in range(1, 1001):
    X_train, y_train = dataset.iloc[i:1000+i], target.iloc[i:1000+i]
    X_test, y_test = dataset.iloc[i], target.iloc[i]

    X_test = np.array(X_test).reshape(1, -1)
    print(X_test.shape)

    SupportVectorRefModel = SVR()
    SupportVectorRefModel.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = SupportVectorRefModel.predict(X_test)
    y_pred_sol.append(y_pred)
```

`print(y_pred_sol)`

Comment: It does not work and looping is still running. Is it possible to solve this problem by using `numpy-array`?

Comment: could you please provide another method to solve this problem